# Is a correct use of this in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used to have this call:

```
var link = $('<a />', { 'class': 'prop' + index, title: elt, text: elt });
link.on('click', switchLabel);
```

with `switchLabel` as follow:

```
function switchLabel(e) {
    $('#' + this.className.replace('prop','corr')).text(this.title);
}
```

I just realized that `this` is quite difficult to understand what it refers to in javascript, so I replaced with:

```
function switchLabel(e) {
    var source = e.currentTarget;
    $('#' + source.className.replace('prop','corr')).text(source.title);
}
```

Am I correct?
Please add some explanation to your answer and we (js noobs) can learn.

Comment: The fact that it's not always easy to determine what `this` refers to in JS doesn't mean that it would just suddenly and randomly start to refer to something else. Did the old code work? If yes, there was no need to change it.

Comment: First of all, I change the question to be clearer about `this` : "quite difficult for me to understand what it refers to".

Comment: @Juhana: you are right, I have a unwanted behavior with this code. The `link.on` is added to a dynamically created `<a />` in a Twitter bootstrap popover. And the first time it triggers `switchLabel`, if the popover is hidden and re-shown, it does not trigger `switchLabel`. So I don't exclude anything.

Comment: js code can be seen at cordial-enligne.fr on line 209 ;) any help is welcome

Comment: There is a lot of answers which can be validated... Sorry for that, I can accept only one answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is incorrect to characterize `this` as being "deeply ambiguous".  In particular, jQuery guarantees that `this` will refer to the "right" element in the handler.

Now, what "right" means may vary based on the way the handler is established, but it's always something that makes sense. For example, when a handler is assigned directly, as in your `.on()` call, then the value of `this` in the handler will be the element (or one of the elements, as appropriate to the actual action taken) from that original selection. In the case of a delegated `.on()`, then `this` will again be the element matching the selector.

That said, there are times when checking `e.target` makes sense or is really necessary; there's nothing particularly *wrong* with doing that, but doing it because of superstition around `this` is kind-of silly.

Comment: I agree superstitions are kind-of silly. That's why I put my pride beside (or [I eat humble pie](http://www.babla.fr/francais-anglais/fiert%C3%A9)) and ask my lovely stackoverflow.

Answer (score 4):

`this` is not really ambiguous, you just have to understand the scopes / closures. nevertheless, if `switchLabel` is a generic function, you shouldn't use `this`, if its only use, now and forever, is as a callback/handler to a (jQuery) event, you can rely on `this`

Comment: `this` is unrelated to scopes and closures.

Comment: i was referring to the possibility to `apply` other objects to the function, and the common technique to save `this` in a local variable to use it in nested functions. i have read in a lot of tutorials something like "dont use `this`, but `var t = this ...`. i think enguerrans confusion might originate in something like this

Comment: exactly: someone tells me "dont use `this` but `var t = this` in nested functions.

Answer (score 1):

`e.currentTarget` and `this` are no more worse one than the other in your use. They'll both be present without the need for a lookup, and they'll both have the same value in **most** cases. There are some cases, however, where `e.currentTarget` will not exist.

`this` is not ambiguous, by the way. It is all a matter of scoping, something jQuery does very well. When you use `this` inside a jQuery callback, you can be guaranteed that `this` will be the current element/structure you are acting on. There is no ambiguity.

Comment: Except for ajax callback

Comment: @roasted: Disagree. http://tinker.io/cedd9 for a fiddle - `this` is, logically, the AJAX settings, which also contains the XHR object.

Comment: Ya, but it's not reference to XHR object himself but his settings

Comment: @roasted: this actually makes sense. You're indirectly calling the XHR. `this` in this case allows you to keep the abstraction going **and** get the settings you used to spawn the XHR. Perfectly logical.

Comment: your explanations are clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you bind handler with JQuery, `this` will always refer to event callee.

Instead of manipulating with classes, try this:

```
var link = $('<a />', { 'class': 'prop' + index, 'ind':index, title: elt, text: elt });
link.on('click', switchLabel);

function switchLabel(e) {
    $('#corr'+$(this).attr("ind")).text($(this).attr("title"));
}
```